# Salesforce SOAP Login request doesn't return Access-Control-Allow-Origin in server side

Tags: soap, login, cors

We are trying to establish username-password authorization from javascript (visualforce or lightning) but this doesn't work.

We are trying to login from Organization A to Organization B.

POST request payload is the following

```
'<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'
                    + '<Header/><Body><login xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">'
                    + '<username>' + USERNAME + '</username><password>' + PASSWORD + '</password>'
                    + '</login></Body></Envelope>'
```

and it is sent to  http://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/43.0.

It is working fine from POSTMAN but it is not working from Visualforce page because the following error is failing

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

We tried to use custom login domain and we tried to add everything to whitelist like it is [described here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=extend_code_cors.htm&type=5).

Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like SOAP API which is used for username and password authentication doesn't support CORS since it is not listed in this document

> These Salesforce technologies support CORS.
>
> Analytics REST API
>
> Bulk API
>
> Chatter REST API
>
> Salesforce IoT REST API
>
> Lightning Out
>
> REST API
>
> User Interface API
>
> Apex REST

And looks like CORS doesn't support resources used for authentication

> IMPORTANT CORS does not support requests for unauthenticated
>   resources, including OAuth endpoints. You must pass an OAuth token
>   with requests that require it.

So it is impossible to implement username and password Salesforce authentication in javascript.